# What is 'Evolutionary Development Methodology'?

Tags: android, oop, object-oriented-analysis, mobile-development

What is 'Evolutionary Development Methodology' means in the context of Mobile Development (Android)?

Is there any similarity to 'Object Oriented Methodology' as well? Does someone have an example piece of code?

Comment: I think OO is a programming paradigm (like "functional paradigm", etc), while evolutionary development is a project lifecycle management or something like that (that you can apply in agile development in extreme programming or scrum) http://www.agiledata.org/essays/evolutionaryDevelopment.html

Comment: so how the cording style should be ?

Comment: The coding style? OO or functional, whatever your task requires.

Comment: Evolutionary algorithms are similar to Genetic algorithms, and not relevant to this question as what op is asking is about the development paradigm.

Comment: looks like some agile stuff: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/evolutionaryDevelopment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood so far Evolutionary development is an iterative and incremental approach to software development. We can use this on an Agile project mostly.

- See more at: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/evolutionaryDevelopment.html#sthash.2Qv09tdE.dpuf

Answer (score 3):

Evolutionary Development Methodology is a registered Trade Mark of Redwing Business Intelligence Ltd.  It is not a generic term.

It is used to develop Business Intelligence systems and to manage Business Intelligence programmes.  It uses the following principles:

- Evolutionary.  Each chunk of business value provided to the business
  – each Release – builds upon previous work.  Each outer spiral
  iteration adds new business value to the business.
- Incremental.  In all respects, EDM development work is step-by-step.
- Collaborative.    The work is driven by business needs and information consumer
  requirements, with the business user playing a vital part of the
  development process.
- Iterative.  Each inner spiral iteration adds
  value to the work being delivered.

You can find more information at [the EDM website](http://www.evolutionary-development.co.uk/)

By the way, EDM has nothing to do with Android development.  An appropriate methodology for Android Apps would be one of the Agile (note the capital A) methodologies such as Scrum.

Evolutionary Development Methodology(TM) is a Spiral methodology, and not an Agile methodology.  EDM's cadence and rhythms are much longer than for Agile; the spirals within spirals within spirals of EDM are more tuned to working in a embedded/collaborative manner with the business, than separate stand-alone software development.

Comment: Thanks @Donna Kelly